# Reset link using nodejs, mongodb and react is not working, localhost refused to connect. "This site can't be reached"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

The link is successfully sent to the user's email address, however upon clicking the link, I get a "This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
My objective: When a user clicks on the link via email, that link directs the user to go change his/her password

BACKEND CODE (Routes)

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
import cors from "cors";
app.use(cors());
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
const router = express.Router();

import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import  nodemailer from "nodemailer";


const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT


const User = mongoose.model("User");


//getting the data/email from the database

router.post("/userData", async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
     const email = user.email;
    User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then((data) => {
        res.send({ status: "ok", data: data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.send({ status: "error", data: error });
      });
  } catch (error) {}
});


router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  try {
    const oldUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!oldUser) {
      return res.json({ status: "Email does not exist!" });
    }
    const secret = JWT_SECRET + oldUser.password;
    const token = jwt.sign({ email: oldUser.email, id: oldUser._id }, secret, {
      expiresIn: "15m",
    });
    const link = `http://localhost:3000/reset-password/${oldUser._id}/${token}`;
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: 'gmail@gmail.com',
        pass: '1234567890123456',
      },
    });

    var mailOptions = {
      from: 'gmail@gmail.com',
      to: email,
      subject: "Password Reset",
      text: link,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      }
    });
    console.log(link);
  } catch (error) {}
});


export default router;

//id and token are params, structure of the link   
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { id, token } = req.params;
  console.log(req.params);
  const oldUser = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
  if (!oldUser) {
    return res.json({ status: "User Not Exists!!" });
  }
  const secret = JWT_SECRET + oldUser.password;
  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(token, secret);
    res.render("index", { email: verify.email, status: "Not Verified" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send("Not Verified");
  }
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { id, token } = req.params;
  const { password } = req.body;

  const oldUser = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
  if (!oldUser) {
    return res.json({ status: "User does not exist" });
  }
  const secret = JWT_SECRET + oldUser.password;
  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(token, secret);
    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    await User.updateOne(
      {
        _id: id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          password: encryptedPassword,
        },
      }
    );
    

    res.render("index", { email: verify.email, status: "verified" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json({ status: "Something Went Wrong" });
  }
});

Backend Index.js 

import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config();


import forgotPasswordRouter from "./routes/passwordReset.js"
import resetPasswordRouter from "./routes/passwordReset.js"

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors());


app.use("/forgot-password", forgotPasswordRouter);
app.use("/reset-password/:id/:token", resetPasswordRouter )

const CONNECTION_URL = encodeURI(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS);
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is active on port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

FRONT_END CODE
PasswordReset.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, {useState, useEffect, Fragment} from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const PasswordReset = () => {
    const [validUrl, setValidUrl] = useState(false);
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
    const param = useParams();
    const link = `http://localhost:3000/reset-password/${param.id}/${param.token}`

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyUrl = async() => {
        try {
            await axios.get(link);
            setValidUrl(true)
        } catch (error) {
            setValidUrl(false)
        }
    };
    verifyUrl()
  }, [param, link]);

  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(link, { password });
        setMsg(data.message)
        window.location = "/auth"
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  };

    return (
       <Fragment>
        {validUrl ? (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <h1>Create new password</h1>
                    <input 
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter password"
                    name="name"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
        )}
       </Fragment>
    )
};

export default PasswordReset;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import ForgotPassword from './components/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword';
import PasswordReset from './components/PasswordRest/PasswordReset';


const App = () => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
 

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <Route path="/forgot-password" exact component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route path="/reset-password/:id/:token" exact component={ PasswordReset } />
        </Switch>
      </Container>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What/where can I change my code so that my objective becomes a success? I get no errors when I inspect the console, except for a "crbug/1173575, non-JS modules files deprecated"

Comment: What port of localhost are you visiting? Can you ensure that both your React server and Express is running?

Comment: localhost:3000 for front-end and localhost:5000 for backend. Yes, they are running because I am able to add new email addresses to my database(mongodb). I mean, I can add new email address via my front-end to my database, the forgot-password button will work on the front-end. The problem starts when I click on that link sent via email by the "forgot-password" button

Comment: in the passwordreset.jsx, I am supposed to get the link from localhost:5000, that's why I was getting no connection

Comment: Are you sure your server is running on port 5000? Read your logs and see if it says 5000 or something else. Then try visiting http://localhost:5000 and see what happens.